# R: Applying Regression on Dataset with Factors

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have the following dataset:
[image]

And I'm trying to apply Multilinear Regression to the training and testing datasets accordingly as shown below:

```
library(caTools)

set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(data$G3, SplitRatio = 0.8)
train_set = subset(data, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(data, split == FALSE)

write.csv(train_set, "student_train.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(test_set, "student_test.csv", row.names = FALSE)

#Multilinear regression
multi = lm(formula = G3 ~ ., data = train_set)

#Predicting the test values
y_pred_m = predict(multi, newdata = test_set)

library(Metrics)

mae_m = mae(test_set[[10]], y_pred_m)
rmse_m = rmse(test_set[[10]], y_pred_m)
```

However, both my mae and rmse values are coming back as **NA** in the console and as **NA_real_** in the Environment tab. My `data$G3` value is not a factor so I'm unsure why I get the following error message: `In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors.` I'm new to using R for Regression so please help.

Comment: Rather than include a screenshot of the data, it would be helpful if you pasted the output `dput(data)` into the text of your question. That would allow others to reproduce the dataset locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tenth column is the factor, `internet`. So it should be

```
mae_m = mae(test_set$G3, y_pred_m)
rmse_m = rmse(test_set$G3, y_pred_m)
```